# How to integrate Socket Mobile Scanner with iOS app

Tags: objective-c, mobile, barcode-scanner, socketscan

My company is trying to use Socket Mobile bluetooth scanner to scan the labels on product. I need to integrate this scanner with-in my iPad app so that when user scans a label , then scanned value comes to user's app and that value can be used for further processing.

Can someone help me in this that how can I integrate Socket Mobiles CHS with my iOS code? Company wants to decide for scanner to use or no.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options HID and SDK

### HID (aka quick and dirty)

Put your scanner in HID mode and it will behave like a bluetooth keyboard.

**Pros**

1. Scan into input fields in any existing app
2. Scan into the browser
3. No integration required

**Cons**

1. Limited ability for processing scanned data
2. No control over where scanned input goes
3. On screen keyboard doesn't auto-hide/appear

In HID mode, the scanner "types" data under the cursor. This means data can be scanned into the wrong field and the text input must be editable, so the user can modify the scanned value. You can configure the scanner to append a tab or return character to the scanned data.

HID mode is great for proof-of-concept type applications and is the only option for browser based applications at the moment.

### SDK (aka doing it right)

Personally, I've never developed an iOS application using the SDK, so the best I can do is refer you to this [create an iOS barcode scanner application video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVkwVp-0nwM#t=25) on youtube.

**Pros**

Total control over scanned data

1. Direct input to different fields based on pattern or barcode type
2. Prevent the user from editing the scanned data
3. Coerce the barcode into the desired format, before continuing
4. Take automatic action upon receipt of a scan

**Cons**

1. Not a turnkey solution for existing apps
2. Does not work in the browser

*Full disclosure*: I am a consultant to Socket Mobile, Inc.

Comment: I looked into Youtube video and its using ScanAPI which is SDK provided by MobileConnect. I am not sure from where i can get the ScanAPI or we will have to buy this from MobileConnect

Comment: No [ScanAPI](http://www.socketmobile.com/Developer/) is provided by Socket Mobile

Comment: @Enrico what do you think of [this](http://www.deadosaurus.com/detect-a-usb-barcode-scanner-with-javascript/) with a socket mobile scanner and the dirt solution?